# Can this subquery be made to use the index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

First, apologies in advance for the wall of text.  I did read through every similar question/answer I could find, but either the answers didn't seem applicable to my query, or I needed more clarity to understand the underlying problem and solution.

I have a table of file sizes along with related file dates and observation timestamps.  All dates are UNIX epoch time integers in seconds:

```
mysql> describe name_servers;
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| server_name           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| file_date             | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| file_size             | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time                  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| poll_id               | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> show index from name_servers;
+--------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| name_servers |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | poll_id     | A         |     3523218 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| name_servers |          0 | index_time_servername    |            1 | time        | A         |      503316 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| name_servers |          0 | index_time_servername    |            2 | server_name | A         |     3523218 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have to track file size changes to detect if the file shrinks by > 20% in any 48 hour period.  Normally I would try to do this with MySQL Window functions, but they are not supported by the MySQL version on my server (5.6.37 -- which I have no control over as the server is not managed by my team).  Presently I obtain the current size and maximum size (in the last 48 hours) by means of an outside query that finds the file size in the current row, and an inside subquery that finds the largest file size in the previous 48 hours (172,800 seconds) worth of rows:

```
mysql> select name_servers_outside.server_name,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_size,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_date,
    -> name_servers_outside.time,
    -> (select max(file_size) from name_servers where time > (name_servers_outside.time - 172800) and server_name = 'example_server') as max_file_size
    -> from name_servers as name_servers_outside
    -> where name_servers_outside.server_name = 'example_server'
    -> and name_servers_outside.time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800)
    -> limit 10;
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| server_name       | file_size         | file_date         | time       | max_file_size         |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550382985 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383195 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383255 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383316 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383376 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383435 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383496 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383555 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383616 |               1159580 |
| example_server    |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383676 |               1159580 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (16.11 sec)
```

Just retrieving those 10 rows took 16 sec, and in production, this query will have to retrieve over 150 rows.  The inner query is doing a complete scan of all 3 million+ table rows, with the message **"Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2)":**

```
mysql> explain
    -> select name_servers_outside.server_name,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_size,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_date,
    -> name_servers_outside.time,
    -> (select max(file_size) from name_servers where time > (name_servers_outside.time - 172800) and server_name = 'example_server') as max_file_size
    -> from name_servers as name_servers_outside
    -> where name_servers_outside.server_name = 'example_server'
    -> and name_servers_outside.time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800);
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                | type  | possible_keys            | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                          |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | name_servers_outside | range | index_time_servername    | index_time_servername    | 5       | NULL |   47302 | Using index condition; Using MRR               |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | name_servers         | ALL   | index_time_servername    | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL | 3533883 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The problematic part seems to be this:

```
time > (name_servers_outside.time - 172800)
```

If I run a similar query using a static integer value instead of the "name_servers_outside.time" column reference in the subquery, the indexes are used as expected and the query is fast:

```
time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800)
```

The modified query:

```
mysql> select name_servers_outside.server_name,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_size,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_date,
    -> name_servers_outside.time,
    -> (select max(file_size) from name_servers where time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800) and server_name = 'example_server') as max_file_size
    -> from name_servers as name_servers_outside
    -> where name_servers_outside.server_name = 'example_server'
    -> and name_servers_outside.time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800)
    -> limit 10;
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| server_name        | file_size         | file_date         | time       | max_file_size         |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550382985 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383195 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383255 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383316 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383376 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383435 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383496 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383555 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383616 |               1159580 |
| example_server     |           1159544 |        1550382945 | 1550383676 |               1159580 |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> explain
    -> select name_servers_outside.server_name,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_size,
    -> name_servers_outside.file_date,
    -> name_servers_outside.time,
    -> (select max(file_size) from name_servers where time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800) and server_name = 'example_server') as max_file_size
    -> from name_servers as name_servers_outside
    -> where name_servers_outside.server_name = 'example_server'
    -> and name_servers_outside.time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800)
    -> limit 10;
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys            | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | name_servers_outside | range | index_time_servername    | index_time_servername    | 5       | NULL | 49042 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | name_servers         | range | index_time_servername    | index_time_servername    | 5       | NULL | 49042 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you for reading with me this far.  I apologize again for the giant wall of text, but I wanted to make sure I included enough explanatory detail to clearly define the problem.

Now, the problem I'm trying to solve is that I need to retrieve the largest value of file_size in the 48 hours preceding each row.  Each row therefore has its own unique time range for the "max(file_size)" calculation.  This will then be used to calculate the percent file size change.  As mentioned above, I normally want to use window functions for this, but they are not supported by my version of MySQL (5.6.37), and it's not within my ability to update to 8.0 as I don't own this server.

As always, any suggestions are appreciated.  Thank you for reading!

Comment: Welcome to SO, and dont apologize for the wall of text. This is typically an excellent formatted question with all the details needed to solve it. Proof : you got upvotes.

Comment: Do you get different performances when you try adding additional single-column indices like on `time` or even the `file_size` column? Or maybe some weird index on the column sequence `(server_name, file_size)`?

Comment: Could you create a playground for this ? Choose among [Rextester](https://rextester.com/) or  [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Make your CREATE TABLE statement, and INSERT enough rows for a decent test. Then we can easily test anything we want.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try adding file_size to your index_time_servername index but I suspect the real issue is that you're having to use name_servers_outside.time inside your subquery which being from a different alias is probably confusing the query planner.

So, how about losing the subquery and join the table to itself where time is between time and time-48-hours-ago?

Something like...

```
SELECT
  name_servers_outside.server_name,
  name_servers_outside.file_size,
  name_servers_outside.file_date,
  name_servers_outside.time,
  MAX(previous.file_size) AS max_file_size
FROM
   name_servers AS ns
INNER JOIN name_servers AS previous 
   ON previous.time BETWEEN (ns.time - 172800) AND (ns.time - 1)
WHERE 
   ns.server_name = 'example_server'
   AND ns.time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 172800)
GROUP BY
   ns.server_name,
   ns.file_size,
   ns.file_date,
   ns.time
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delayed reply; the solution ended up involving several components, and it took time to work through and test them.

The primary issue I was trying to resolve was one of query performance.  Strictly speaking, my original query returned the expected data, but it took so long to complete that it was not practical.  So the solution was all about finding as many ways as possible to reduce execution time.

Here is what the solution finally entailed:

1. Per Dazz Knowles' suggestion, I replaced the subquery with an Inner Join, and this cleaned up the code and made it easier to comprehend.
2. As Progman suggested, I changed my index to a single column index on the "server_name" field.
3. I moved the rows involved in this query into their own table, thus simplifying the working set of columns.
4. I reduced the sample rate of the application writing rows to the table from 1 data point (1 row) per minute to 1 data point (1 row) per hour, thus reducing the working set of rows to 1/60th the previous quantity.  The combined effects of 1-4 got the query execution time down from a handful of minutes to a handful of milliseconds.
5. I was previously trying to calculate "max_file_size" at run time, with the application client submitting the query to the MySQL server simultaneously for ~100 different servers and 3 different files on each server (~300 instances of the query running every time the application refreshed).  This was keeping the MySQL server's CPU @ 100%, so not practical for real world use, especially with multiple end users simultaneously using the client side application.  I changed to running the query only from the server side scripts and only when new rows are inserted.  So the query runs once per hour, calculating ~300 max_file_size values in a handful of milliseconds.  It then writes max_file_size as a static column to the MySQL table.  None of the values that max_file_size depends on should ever change, so I'm not worried about needing to run the query again to update max_file_size once it's written for a particular row.  The client side of the application now only reads the data from MySQL; it no longer attempts to send a query to calculate max_file_size.  With the benefit of hindsight, it seems like this approach should have been obvious from the beginning, but sometimes you have to do it wrong first to understand what makes the right approach right.